# OpenFileDialog Filter Option Not Working

Tags: vb.net, filter, backgroundworker, openfiledialog

Since I put my OpenFileDialog into a BackgroundWorker, the `Filter` option no longer works.

I use to have this as a button click and it worked fine, with the exception of what every file I opened it wouldn't close the file, hence I added the BackgroundWorker.

Anywho, here's my current code, nothing different from the button click code I had.

```
Dim OpenFileDialog2 As New OpenFileDialog()

OpenFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = "C:\Temp\Config_Files\"
OpenFileDialog2.Filter = "Configuration Files (*.cfg)|*.cfg"
```

Is there something I need to add to make this work properly?

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you think that a backgroundworker could help you to close your files?

Comment: I'm opening a config a file and reading the contents into a textbox. I also my have to modify the file and save a new config file. For some reason, if I modified the file and tried to save too quickly, I received an access violation. I got the idea from here: http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/windows-forms/43990-closing-openfiledialog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are misunderstanding the advice to use a backgroundworker.
You should let the OpenFileDialog do its work and grab the cfg file to be processed, then, if you want a faster UI response start the backgroundworker.

```
Dim fileToProcess as String = string.Empty
Using opf As New OpenFileDialog()
    opf.InitialDirectory = "C:\Temp\Config_Files\"
    opf.Filter = "Configuration Files (*.cfg)|*.cfg"
    if opf.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK then
        fileToProcess = opf.FileName
    Endif
End Using
if fileToProcess <> string.Empty then
    ' Now start you backgroundworker to do its job
end if
```

Of course, the user could re-start againg the same code and select again the same file. This could lead to unexpected results. Better to disable the Button/Menu or whatever that start the file selection process till the previous process ends.